# C# Windows Forms application hangs and need help reading the error log

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, reportviewer

After the latest release of my application, users are experiencing application "locks" where the program just remains unresponsive. This occurs at different times and never after a specific action.
At one point I found an entry in the Windows Error Logs, but I can't figure out what's happening there.

My main questions:

- anyone experienced anything like this with ReportViewer in Windows Forms application?
- Can someone explain the attached error log (please excuse the Dutch)

[image]

**Update**
Still no idea on how to fix this issue. Application keeps randomly freezing with different users. Everytime an application-hang is preceeded by the above mentioned .NET Runtime error and event 10016 (DistributedCOM). I have tried to resolve the DCOM issue by following [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/error-event-id-10016-distributedcom/130522d2-beac-4495-980a-65e1e3279901?auth=1), but that did not solve the problems.
Also, I have made sure that all the forms with reportviewers (only 4) and every method that has to do with reportviewer operations have proper errorhandling.

Further explanations: from a windows form I open another form which contains a reportviewer. I show this form as a dialog.

Comment: Some info on _Canon...it is not related to a printer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854393/strange-system-canon-exception#16856205

Comment: Could you check if the code (hot-coded) refers Canon printer?

Comment: Het enige wat ik op kan maken uit die stacktrace is dat de `Reportviewer` control tijdens een `dispose` is gecrasht. `__Canon` heeft niets te maken met printers (ook al heten die net zo), maar is in dit geval een afkorting voor "Canonical" (zie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854393/strange-system-canon-exception)

Comment: Balagurunathan Marimuthu, it doesn't

Comment: Timothy Groote: ok thanks for that. Could it be that this could occur when I call a RefreshReport (which is async) and then the window containing the control is closed?

Comment: @F43G4N yes, you will end up getting cross-thread access calls, which can cause this kind of mess.

Comment: if you want to keep the operation async, you will need to use a dispatcher or a similar structure. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303116/system-windows-threading-dispatcher-and-winforms

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm removing the refreshes to the reports as nothing can change to the content of it. So no need to make/have/keep it asynchronous. I can't remember why I even did the RefreshReport and when inspecting all forms using ReportViewer I even found one that did 2 right after eachother.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the refreshes did not solve the problem of the application freezing. I think I need to build in extensive debugging options and logging to be able to trace the issue. Unless someone else has an idea what kind of issue I am experiencing... And the application is being used by 7 or 8 people simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

After long inspection I found the culprit: in a new process which was started in a backgroundworker a form with a reportviewer was opened but never disposed. Closing the form and disposing it solved my issue.